# Android, elevation attribute ignored by LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-elevation

I am trying to add elevation to various components of my app to give it a little more material look.  Directly below the layout that is giving me issues, I have a LinearLayout that is casting a shadow on its sibling, but this element will not show a shadow and I cannot figure out why.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_control_block"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:color="@color/white"
    android:elevation="8dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/inputModeSelector"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="@color/cyan"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_assignment_white_18dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text=" Text"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/addNoteButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@color/cyan"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_circle_outline_white_18dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/alarmEnableButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="@color/cyan"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_notifications_off_white_18dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="None"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/edit_text_block"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">
//sibling element shadow should be cast on
```

Comment: Are you using a 5.+ SDK and/or supported 5.+ device for this? Or what appCompat version are you using?

Comment: I'm using API 23 on a Nexus 6P emulator on Android Studio 1.4, I can see the elevation working on other elements, just not this one.

Comment: Well, how about the LinearLayout parent? does it have a match_parent on it's height? if not, the linear layout is not able to show it

Comment: It does, I have four main children: LinearLayout, LinearLayout, LinearLayout, and ListView.  LinearLayout 3 has elevation 8dp and shows its shadow on ListView, but LinearLayout 1 will not comply.

Comment: I think you should change your 'android:color' property to 'android:background'

Comment: Jesus, I'm an idiot.  That's exactly what it was.  It wouldn't display on other elements without a background that wasn't transparent, guess I made a typo.  I'm blind sometimes, thank you very much.

Comment: I am glad to help you, but, why did you commented the answer?